# minikube kubectl create file error (validating data: apiVersion not set)

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubectl, minikube

I am a student and new to minikube as well as linux. My Teacher did the same and his pod created but i am getting error. I don't know what is the problem. Should i ignore validation error?

```
kubectl create -f myfirstpod.yaml
error: error validating "myfirstpod.yaml": error validating data: apiVersion not set; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

cat myfirstpod.yaml

```
 kind: Pod
 apiversion: v1
 metadata:
   name: myfirstpod
 spec:
   containers:
 name: container1
 image: aamirpinger/helloworld:latest
 ports:
   containerPort: 80
```

I am using these versions:

- minikube version: v1.11.0
- kubectl version 1.8.4
- Kubernetes 1.18.3
- Docker 19.03.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you have typo. It should be `apiVersion` instead of `apiversion`. Also, the indentation in the PodSpec seems incorrect.

You can use this:

```yaml
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myfirstpod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container1
    image: aamirpinger/helloworld:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: Thanks, i did mistake in writing capital V in "apiVersion" .

Comment: It was my first post ton stackoverflow that's why i didn't know the format to keep indetation. Thanks again